# FOR XML PATH doesn't work with 0x001E character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, for-xml-path

I've checked : https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/ 
So, my query is:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, NAME, DOCTEXT2
  FROM DOC
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT 
     Stuff((SELECT ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(DOCTEXT))  
        FROM DOC d 
        WHERE d.ID=DOC.ID AND d.NAME = DOC.NAME 
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,'')
  ) D (DOCTEXT2)
```

The error is :

> FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'NoName' because it
>   contains a character (0x001E) which is not allowed in XML. To retrieve
>   this data using FOR XML, convert it to binary, varbinary or image data
>   type and use the BINARY BASE64 directive.

I know I've 0x001E characters in the data. I don't want to replace this data in the database.

My data are :

```
 ID NAME    DOCTEXT 
 12 AB      ERROR INSTRUCTIONS                                        
 12 CC      CRN   70                             SS 
 12 CC      DRF 77                                 
 12 CC
```

What I'm trying to have is, something like:

```
 ID NAME    DOCTEXT 
 12 AB      ERROR INSTRUCTIONS                             
 12 CC      CRN   70 SS DRF 77
```

The query is working if the data doesn't have 0x001E character(s).

**EDIT :**

I tried: 
`CAST ( REPLACE( DOCTEXT, char(0), '') AS VARCHAR)` instead of `RTRIM(LTRIM(DOCTEXT))`, without success.

Comment: Try using 'nvarchar' instead of 'varchar'

Comment: I tried, without success

Comment: Maybe prefer to this link: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic677554-338-1.aspx Its contains additional information and another option  to resolve this problem.

Comment: If possible, I prefer a "general" fix instead of convert each ASCII in int and then char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clunky, but you can convert back and forth between `VARBINARY(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in hexstrings to avoid any issue with characters XML doesn't like in text:

```
;WITH D1 AS (
  SELECT ID, NAME
  FROM DOC
  GROUP BY ID, NAME
)
SELECT D1.ID, D1.NAME, DOCTEXT = 
  LTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), D.DOCTEXT, 2)))
FROM D1 CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT NULLIF(
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(D2.DOCTEXT))), 2), 
    0x)
  FROM DOC D2 
  WHERE D2.ID = D1.ID AND D2.[NAME] = D1.[NAME]
  FOR XML PATH('')
) D(DOCTEXT)
```

We can't use `BINARY BASE64` here, because concatenating two Base64 strings does not (generally) yield another Base64 string. The outer `LTRIM()` takes care of removing the initial space; use `STUFF` instead for more precise results if you like, but since we're trimming spaces of the internal strings it doesn't matter here.

Note that there are other approaches for concatenating strings (most notably `STRING_AGG` in SQL Server 2017) and the article you linked to mentions them. This approach is not necessarily the best in terms of performance, but I haven't measured.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, the result is in Chineses or seems to be (I don't speak Chineses) :  `䨠䉏䔠剒剏䤠华剔䍕䥔乏⁓‭䕒呓剁⁔剆䵏䈠䝅义䥎䝎ⴠ丠O`

Comment: Good catch, I didn't take the base column type into account. You'll have to use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ...` rather than `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in the outer query if your column is `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Working! It didn't delete spaces, but I don't have any error now. I'll work on it :)

Comment: Your original query explicitly added spaces to separate the columns, so I copied that. If you don't want that, simply leave out the `' ' +`. If you want to remove *all* spaces, even inside strings, that's another problem altogether.

Comment: Never mind, I did an error. Thanks for your help! It's working perfectly!